# How to set CSS rule for a LI in a UL nested in DIV with class?

Tags: html, css, joomla, css-selectors

I use component Sp page builder in Joomla. I need to set padding for li. 
This example my css:

```
li.upad
{
  padding: 3px;
}
```

I can add a css rule only  for Div (It's definitely a component specifics).

```
<div class="upad">
<ul >
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

How do I write a correct css rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div.upad > ul > li { padding: 3px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to add the padding rule to all `<li>`s in the parent div. It's a simple case of a CSS descendant (' ') selector:

```
.upad li {
    padding: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Side note: it's generally considered best practice in CSS to have your opening brace { on the same line as the selector

Answer (score 0):

Hi now you can used to this

```
.result > li{
    padding:3px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use like  -

```
ul.result li{
  padding: 3px;
}
```

Or

```
.upad ul li{
   padding: 3px;
}
```